# Uninstall last batch of windows updates

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, updates

Last night my PC here at work automatically installed updates, I have it set to do that of course. This morning I tried to start Virtualbox and unfortunately it no longer starts due to the updates. Turns out Virtualbox is hardening its security and after a lot of searching it appears one or more of the recent updates from last night broke Virtualbox.

Is there any way I can batch uninstall the last round of updates automatically? Like an undo? I looked in add/remove programs and under updates there are dozens of updates with todays date on them. I really need VB up and running.

Comment: You can use a restore point, if this was 8 or above, there is a way from within WinRE to uninstall an update

Comment: I have all the latest Win 7 updates as of today, and VBox still works fine. So is the problem you're trying to solve "how to undo the updates?", or is it actually "Help! My VBox won't start for some reason"?

Comment: The issue is Windows Updates hosed Vbox. I want to undo the updates and get Vbox running so I can get work done. Everything was working yesterday so it must be the updates. There are many other people having the same issues: [link](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=64111&sid=af779af6b3d585f2a016a7939495f5e9). I have been working on the problem and I partly solved it by rolling back the virtualbox version but that is breaking the VM's.

Answer (score 0):

System Restore is your friend.  Before the automatic updates, Windows Update most likely created a system restore point.

1. Turn off automatic updates temporarily
2. Go to your Start Menu, type 'system restore' and select the most recent restore date.
3. Get your work done with Virtualbox
4. Determine problem with VB and the updates and resolve it
5. Turn automatic updates back on

Comment: System restore is disabled for some reason. I am not the only person to have used this PC and it is possible my predecessor disabled it.

Comment: And I spoke too soon. Apparently it was on but the transaction log was corrupted as I was recieving an error 0x8007000B when trying to change the system restore settings.